# Why am I getting a JsonSyntaxException here?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

I am experiencing a JSON parsing error. My code is as follows:

```
try {
        //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        List<JsonObject> posts = (List) gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);

        Log.e(TAG, "Results Size: " + posts.size());

        //  for(int i=0; i<posts.size(); i++){
        //      Log.e(TAG, "Checking: " + posts.get(i).title());
        //  }

        content.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
}
```

I get the following error from my `posts.size()` check:

> Failed to parse JSON due to: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

For the JSON I am trying to read, if successful my `posts.size()` should be returning 5.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem stems from the fact that you're trying to deserialize to a generic type (a `List`). The [documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29) states that in this case you need to pass in a `Type` rather than a `Class` to the `fromJson()` method. Try this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>(){}.getType();
List<JsonObject> posts = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it mentions in the exception line, your `JSON` starts with `[` so it indicates a `JSON Array` rather than a `JSON Object`, but `JSON` have to start with a `JSON Object`. So wrap your `JSON` file with `{ }` couple (add `{` to at beginning and `}` to end). It should resolve the issue.